# How to replace ajax call with $http, AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to implement angular.js in my php file, Because it's only one file project, So I am thinking where I use AngularJS. So i decided to replace AJAX call with `$http`.

For this i imported google angular js file

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And replace my this ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(res) {
        resData = res;
    }
});
```

With

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    data: data
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    resData = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    resData = data;
});
```

beside these nothing changed, but when i am trying to execute my code, I am getting this error

> $http is not defined

Comment: You need to inject `$http`, Show the complete code where you are using `$http`

Comment: Did you inject $http to your function ?

Comment: You need something like this
`myNgApp.controller("myController", function($http){
// your code
});`

Comment: here is my complete code   http://pastebin.com/1wX2z2G6  . I didn't created any angular controller or anything else. And how i inject $http?

Comment: @ketansharma, AngularJS is not a library like jQuery __its a Framework__

Comment: OMG the `Clearchart()` function contains 56 calls to elements with IDs to hide them, don't you know classes? With a class, you could replace 56 lines with one. Like `$(".someclass").hide()`, job done. What if you had 8000 elements to hide, would you duplicate 8000 lines of code?

Comment: Actually that's my code, my job is to cleanup this code and made this optimize, Thanks for point-out this, i will also look on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use $http you first need to inject it into your controller

```
var module = angular.module('putNameHere', [])
module.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', function($http){  //injection here
    $http({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        data: data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resData = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        resData = data;
    });
}])
```

Comment: module is not defined

Comment: You have to load a module first...check my answer.

Comment: module is generic for var module = angular.module('nameYourOwn', []);

Comment: Why my call is not going to $http?  http://pastebin.com/xHKhcE3r  I am not able to see console messages.

Comment: You're using it incorrectly, angular is a framework not a library that you inject into your jQuery code.  You will need to set everything up, from the HTML to the module codes.

Comment: Almost there, use `.catch` instead of `.error`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to actually load an angular module and controller, then inject $http into the controller:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('HttpCtrl', function($http) { //this is the $http injection here
  //insert your $http code here
})
</script>
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview) (change google.com to whatever url you need to use)

You will also need to add the ng-app='app' attribute to your `<html>` tag, and the ng-controller='HttpCtrl' attribute to your `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error.

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available
  }).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

source https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: That's not correct, this is irrelevant to what the post owner is asking,

Comment: @YangLi please can you explain why it is so ?

Comment: Sorry, it is correct and it's directly a copy and paste from the angular documents.  What I meant is this does not help the post owner in no way nor does this explain the question at hand.

Comment: @YangLi Yes you are correct I realized after reading your answer the actual error is due to not injecting the $http into controller.